# Controller delete function error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an error in my code and don't know why. Here is the error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Display::index() in
```

Here is the controller part that causes the error:

```
 function delete(){
     $this->load->model('display_model');
     $this->display_model->delete_row();
     $this->index();

 }
```

and model part if needed just in case:

```
function delete_row()
          {
             $this->db->where('QID', $this->uri->segment(3));
             $this->db->delete('tblquestions');
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can do like below:

```
function delete(){
     $this->load->model('display_model');
     $this->display_model->delete_row();
     redirect('/controllerName/', 'refresh');
 }
```

The benefit of redirect is that you can set some message to user that you completed or failed to do action by passing some id.

```
function delete(){
     $this->load->model('display_model');
     $this->display_model->delete_row();
     redirect('/controllerName/index/1', 'refresh');
 }
```

Comment: it fixed the error but it dose not delete the selected row in the table

Comment: can u explain more i am new to this daunt really understand what u said ?

Comment: just put "$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);" in your controller so that it will print the query at the bottom of the page(in browser).

Comment: i fixed with the redirect tnx for your help i had a type :)